# Convert from unsigned (8 bit) integer to short integer grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, raster-conversion, taudem

I'm looking to convert a unsigned integer grid to a short integer grid for use in TauDEM. The unsigned integer grid has values ranging from 0 - 4.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If there's only 5 discrete values, a 4-bit image would hold it, in addition to 8-bit and 16-bit. ("short integer" is 16-bit", "integer is 32-bit"; "8-bit is "byte", and 4-bit is "nibble")

Comment: There is actually only 2 discrete values now (0 and 1). This particular analysis tool within TauDEM specifies the input needs to be a short integer grid, although i've used this 8 bit unsigned integer and it seems to have worked. Is there a way to convert it to short integer 16 bit to see if i get the same results? Thanks

Comment: Again, what have you tried?  If you haven't tried a Save As or Export, then you weren't ready to post a question.

Comment: Doing Data > Export Data > Format: GRID gives a 32bit pixel depth.

Comment: From Catalog, right-clicking on the image offers Export -> Raster as Different Format, which pulls up the Copy Raster UI, which has a "Pixel Type (optional)" pull-down

Comment: GRID will ***always*** give a 32-bit depth, because GRID format only supports 32-bit Signed Int and 32-bit IEEE Float.

Answer (score 1):

TauDEM uses three grid data types internally.  These are

- FLOAT_TYPE, corresponding to GDAL GDT_Float32
- SHORT_TYPE, corresponding to GDAL GDT_Int16
- LONG_TYPE, corresponding to GDAL GDT_Int32

It uses the method `GDALRasterIO` to read from whatever grid the user provides into the type that corresponds to the variable being used.  According to http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html this method automatically takes care of data type conversions (which is why it was chosen). So you should not need to convert an unsigned integer grid into a short integer grid to use in TauDEM.